# Windows file permissions, cannot access files

Tags: windows-7, permissions, file-management

I have a folder in Windows 7 ( my Music folder in Libraries ) in which suddenly all files became inaccessible.

When I try to play a music file or just view album cover all programs give me an error about unable to read the file.

First I checked all permissions and everything seems ok. My user have full access over this folder and all enclosed files.

Then I noticed that when I reboot in Debian I can read all files.

When I copy a new file to the folder I can read the new file but still not the old ones.

I noticed that when I copy a file from Music folder to the Desktop I can read it, but still not when it is placed inside the Music folder.

Do you have any idea what can I do to be able to read the files ?

P.S. I just noticed that despite I am the owner of the folder and I have full access, when I view the properties of a single file my user is not in the list of users who have access to the file. When I add my user everything is ok, but I cant to this file by file. Any way to apply this permissions to all files ?

Comment: Have you tried ICACLS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with ICACLS or powershell (see [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2010/11/12/how-to-handle-ntfs-folder-permissions-security-descriptors-and-acls-in-powershell.aspx) for more, the CMD way is much simpler/faster)

Comment: Seems like just "icacls Music /reset /t" did the job. Thank you all who tried to help

Answer (score 0):

In the advanced section of your folder permissions (Music folder) enable inherited permissions for child objects.

Something to that effect.